# Restrict simplecontent element to a formatted list of characters defined by a set of sibling elements' attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have a schema with a root element that has two groups of children:

1. An unbound set of elements which have an attribute called Alias which is restricted by the regex "[\S ]" with maxlength and minlength both equal to 1.  These have an xs:unique restriction as well.
2. A single (required) simplecontent element.

The simplecontent element's content should only allow the characters defined by the Alias attributes of each of the sibling elements, and the \r\n at the end of each line.
It seems this can be done with relative ease if I could use xs:assert, but I want to use Visual Studio as my editor and it doesn't support that version of the xsd standard.

Is what I want to do possible with the technology I want to use?  I couldn't find any examples of using xpath expressions in an xs:pattern node but maybe I'm missing something?

an example xml file for this schema would be

```
<root>
    <a Alias="_"/>
    <a Alias="+"/>
    <a Alias="="/>
    <content>
_=====__+++
===++__++++
+==========
    </content>
</root>
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible as in XSD 1.0 the valid Xpath subset  doesn't allows tests, and the pattern value should be a valid regEx

Comment: That's the conclusion I've been coming to; I was hoping there was something I'd overlooked